# Timer is running inconsistently and not disposed on timer?.cancel() callback in flutter

Tags: flutter, timer

I am working on a quiz app and I need to start a timer when the question is visible. I start the timer periodically and handle seconds as I have to show it to user. For that I just made a `_timer` variable and a seconds variable of type `ValueNotifier<int>` which keeps updating the UI with seconds remaining to answer. Now When a user clicks/select an answer, I need to stop the timer and I call `_timer?.cancel()` but that doesn't work and timer goes on even in minus values. Here is my code for startTimer with variables:

```
//Seconds value to show on UI
final ValueNotifier<int> _seconds = ValueNotifier(60);
//Disbale options after timeout
 final ValueNotifier<bool> _isDisabled = ValueNotifier(false);
  Timer? _timer;
  
  //Code for start timer function
  startTimer() {
    _seconds.value = 60;
    if (_timer != null) {
      _timer!.cancel();
      // Added this to check if this stops the timer.
      _timer = null;
    }
    _timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
      _seconds.value = _seconds.value - 1;
      if (_seconds.value <= 0) {
        _isDisabled.value = true;
        timer.cancel();
        _timer = null;
       
      }
    });
  }
```

Now when a user pressed on any option, I am using inkwell onTap callback to listen for it and cancel timer to stop counting seconds on UI. Here is the code for it:

```
if (_seconds.value != 0 && controller.selectedAnswerIndex == null) {
 // Cancel Timer to stop counting seconds
 _timer?.cancel();
 _timer = null;
 controller.selectedAnswerIndex = index;
}
```

Note that I am using a stateful builder in options to handle when the user taps on a option to rebuild ans show the selection options and show result based on the selection.
I am using single screen and when user clicks on next button, I fetch the next question from backend and start the timer and other values for intended behaviour.
One other thing is my timer is irregular which doesn't seems to run smoothly after 1 second.

Will be very grateful, if anyone help me solve this or provide better solution for this use case.

Comment: Could you provide a simplified version of you full code? It is not clear how you are accessing that _timer_ and updating your UI

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong.  Are these all the sites that use `_timer` and `_seconds`?

Comment: Yes, Everything is ok but the problem is I was testing on emulator and I read somewhere that the timer cancel  operation doesn't work in async methods. So I removed the async operation from method and handle the flow in then callback and it works. I still don't know exactly why this happens in async methods.